# aprilaire manual humidistat always runnig have to turn to off to stop solenoid is it the humidistat

Tags: plumbing

last heating season I replaced a faulty solenoid on my aprilaire 550 furnace humidifier this year noticed water running with furnace off. I turned the manual aprilaire off and the solenoid closed but when I turned the humidistat back on the solenoid opened no matter how low I turner its setting is this a sign of a faulty humidistat ?

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. If you'd care to [edit] to make this a little more readable (proper capitalization, punctuation, etc.) that would make it easier for us to help you.